# I didn't got upgrade option while installing Ubuntu 20.10 from 20.04 by using bootable usb

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, sound, 20.10

Yes, I didn't got upgrade option while installing Ubuntu 20.10 from 20.04 by using bootable usb.

Here is the images where it detected both the Operating System I.e Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 But
Then also it didn't gave the option to upgrade from it...
[Upgrade option not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHP9x.jpg)

Comment: There is no upgrade option on bootable USB.

Comment: I was asking for upgrade from Usb like in Below given images...     ![This has Upgrade option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIGGa.jpg)...

Plz refer given image

Comment: That image has 14.04, and you, apparently, 20.04. Please refer to the image. :~)

Answer (score 0):

That used to be possible in earlier versions (such as 14.04 as in your commented image) but that path to upgrade is no longer available.

The upgrade path now in 20.04 is as in the option set in Software & Updates.

Press the left Windows key and type software then select `Software & Updates` from the icons presented.

Navigate to Updates tab and under Notify me of a new Ubuntu version ensure you have selected `For any new version` from the drop down list.

The system will at some stage then offer you the opportunity to upgrade to the next version (unless you have selected `For long term support versions` when only the next LTS version will be offered)

You can set when to receive notifications in the same tab.

[image]

Comment: I was asking for upgrade from Usb like in Below given images...     ![This has Upgrade option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIGGa.jpg)...

Plz refer given image